# Clean wordpress instalation first load problem php7.4

Tags: php, wordpress

I just downloaded wordpress, copied it to ISPConfig vhost, with php7.4-fpm and got this error when I want to first load WP and configure DB connection.

> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 14720] [client 62.109.143.214:39852] AH01071:
> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to
> undefined function wp_guess_url() in
> /var/www/clients/client1/web31/web/wp-load.php:56\nStack trace:\n#0
> /var/www/clients/client1/web31/web/wp-blog-header.php(13):
> require_once()\n#1 /var/www/clients/client1/web31/web/index.php(17):
> require('/var/www/client...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in
> /var/www/clients/client1/web31/web/wp-load.php on line 56'

PHP7.4-FPM is working I tested it on another site where I already have WordPress and it is working.

Comment: Sounds like your WordPress setup is either missing some files and/or got corrupted. Try reuploading the files again and see if that helps.

Comment: I tryed that is actually weird. Maybe my Ark on linux is somehow corrupted and is not extracting all datas then Weird, but thanks for tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my linux has corrupted or bugged "Ark" (Archiving Tool) and it was not able to extract all datas.

I downloaded WordPress with `wget` on server and copied to `webroot` and it works now.  Thanks @cobrerahector for tip.